# Showing the poster image when video is paused. How to make it smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

Check the codepen, hover over the video and then unhover: https://codepen.io/simii/pen/ZyxKew

I basically have a background image for the video, because if the poster of the video is not the same width and height as the video, it looks bad.

Since I want to show the image when the video is not playing, I reload the video with js (to show the transparent poster and thus the background image).

However, as you can see, it "flickers" when the video is paused, due to the reload.

Anyone has a better, more elegant solution for this?

```
<div class="row container">
  <div class="col-sm-3 video">
    <video id="video1" class="virgin" poster="https://imghost.io/images/2017/07/01/transparent.png" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple things you could do. The easiest would be to have two elements (a poster element and a video element) and hide each other within the mouse enter/leave (like `$('video').css('display','none')`) and so on.

Another option you could do is hacky code - change the size of the video to 0x0 before activating any of the hovers.

The best method for implementhing this, however, is definitely having to elements within col-sm-3 video, one a picture and one a video, which you switch out on hover.

Comment: I agree, probably switching video and image cause a reload for the image. If you simply hide the problem is gone

Comment: Jeez, why didn't I think of that to hide them with only css! I was thinking about literally switching them but it would have been to heavy with actually switching the doms and etc.
Thanks!!